# Enum Flags получить все возможные комбинации с установленным значением

Tags: c#, enum

Есть такой Enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum TypeMoEnum :  long
{
    [EnumMember]
    NotDefined = 0,
    [EnumMember]
    MO = 1,
    [EnumMember]
    Federal = 2,
    [EnumMember]
    Laboratory = 4,
    [EnumMember]
    CallCentre = 8,
    [EnumMember]
    ForRouteCard = 16
}
```

нужно получить все возможные комбинации чисел, которые определяли наличие выбранного члена `ForRouteCard`. Как это можно было бы реализовать ?

UPD:
Условие >= 16 не подойдет, т.к. в дальнейшем могут быть добавлены другие члены енама 32,64 и.т.д

Comment: Если я правильно понял - все, которые `>= 16` (к слову `long` в данном варианте не нужен - максимально возможная комбинация - 31)

Comment: @AGS17 Да, те которые больше, но здесь в дальнейшем может добавится член енама равный 32 и так далее, поэтому просто условие >= 16 не подойдет

Comment: Тогда проще всего рассмотреть, присутствует ли в разложении числа `2^4`

Comment: Я прошу прощения, но чем обычная проверка вас не устраивает?

Comment: @AGS17 Дело в запросе к базе, мне нужно передать туда числа, которые будут соответствовать наличию `ForRouteCard` в выборке, поэтому проверка через HasFlag не подходит. Хотя конечно, как-то можно написать в цикле проверку всех возможных чисел через hasflag, но не знаю как

Comment: @PolyakovSergey, тогда https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-and-transact-sql

Comment: Непонятно, зачем передавать список в базу (да и как это сделать без заморочек)? Если можно проверить нужный флаг сразу на стороне СУБД.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При условии, что TypeMoEnum.ForRouteCard - последний флаг в enum, и что нужно перебрать только те значения, которые отображаются на enum:

```
var values = Enumerable.Range((int)TypeMoEnum.ForRouteCard, (int)TypeMoEnum.ForRouteCard)
    .Select(i => (TypeMoEnum)i);

foreach (var v in values)
{
    Console.WriteLine(v);
}
```

Если флаг не последний, то

```
long maxEnumValue = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TypeMoEnum))
    .Cast<long>()
    .Aggregate(0, (long a, long b) => a | b);

for (long val = (long)TypeMoEnum.ForRouteCard; val <= maxEnumValue; val++)
{
    if ((val & (long)TypeMoEnum.ForRouteCard) != 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((TypeMoEnum)val);
    }
}
```

Comment: Если значение не максимальное в enum'е, то неверно.

Comment: @Qwertiy дописал ограчичения буквально через 5 секунд после коммента :)

Comment: К сожалению, значение не обязательно будет последним, в будущем возможно добавление

Comment: тогда перебирайте циклом от TypeMoEnum.ForRouteCard до комбинации всех флагов в enum и проверяйте на установленность TypeMoEnum.ForRouteCard

Comment: @PolyakovSergey дописал вариант

Comment: Что-то тут половина операций лишние?

Comment: @Qwertiy вполне норм. там все равно запрос в базу, так что пару миллисекунд погоды не сделают. Зато понятно из кода что происходит, без >><< :)

Comment: Если будет 30 значений, то будет очень заметно, наверное? Зачем он енум от лонга наследует, вместо инта?

Comment: @Qwertiy если будет 30 значений - то он не сможет результат выборки пропихнуть в запрос в базу. Даже на диск придется аккуратно сохранять, чтобы не тормозило :)

Comment: @PashaPash, а где там про базу?

Comment: @Qwertiy в последнем комменте к вопросу

Comment: @PashaPash, нашёл коммент. А база что, сама не умеет AND делать? А то что-то это жесть такое в базу пихать. Я-то думал, это для юнит-теста какого надо...

Answer (score 5):

http://ideone.com/Ptvgnu

```
private static IEnumerable<TypeMoEnum> With(TypeMoEnum value)
{
    long lim = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TypeMoEnum)).OfType<TypeMoEnum>().Max(x => (long)x)<<1;
    long val = (long)value, step = val<<1;

    for (long l=val; l<lim; l+=step)
        for (long r=0; r<val; ++r)
            yield return (TypeMoEnum)(l|r);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Если конечная цель выбрать данные из БД, у которых установлен соответствующий флаг - используйте побитовое `И`:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((17 & (long)TypeMoEnum.ForRouteCard) > 0);
        Console.WriteLine((15 & (long)TypeMoEnum.ForRouteCard) > 0);
        Console.WriteLine((31 & (long)TypeMoEnum.ForRouteCard) > 0);
        Console.WriteLine((48 & (long)TypeMoEnum.ForRouteCard) > 0);
        Console.WriteLine((47 & (long)TypeMoEnum.ForRouteCard) > 0);
        Console.WriteLine((117 & (long)TypeMoEnum.ForRouteCard) > 0);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Вывод:

```
True
False
True
True
False
True
```

---

Пример использования в запросах:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IQueryable<TypeMoEnum> queryable = new List<TypeMoEnum>
    {
        (TypeMoEnum)17,
        (TypeMoEnum)15,
        (TypeMoEnum)31,
        (TypeMoEnum)48,
        (TypeMoEnum)47,
        (TypeMoEnum)117
    }.AsQueryable();

    foreach (var q in queryable.Where(v => (v & TypeMoEnum.ForRouteCard) > 0))
        Console.WriteLine((long)q);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Вывод:

```
17
31
48
117
```

Можно даже сообразить метод или метод-расширение, для проверки флага, который передавать в параметре, но сейчас код не приведу, так как не на чем проверить возможные нюансы с `Expression<>` в `IQueryable`